# Zapier Cli - App works fine in Cli but not in Zapier UI

Tags: javascript, api, zapier, zapier-cli

I have created an app in Zapier Cli, that calls [Fancyhands API](https://www.fancyhands.com/developer). Everything works fine in Cli as I get proper response from API as shown below.

[image]

However, when I push this app to Zapier and try to use it. The API gives error, that one of the parameters is not formatted properly.

[image]

However, this shouldn't be the case, as I am sending same parameters from both CLI and the UI. It looks like the Zapier UI is adding some extra encoding to the parameters. Kindly suggest whats going on here?

Comment: You need to format date in the API accepted format.

Comment: I already did it as described here:
https://www.fancyhands.com/api/explorer#/explorer/fancyhands.call.Outgoing

Comment: Where you formatted date? I mean in Zap UI or Your APP coding?

Comment: Its just string as shown in the image.

Comment: You need to format this in your code before sending it to api

Comment: Can you explain how?

Comment: You can use moment js to convert any date-time in API supported format

Comment: Api accepts just a string. I used the string in zapier-cli and it works. However, the same string does not work in zapier-ui.

Comment: @HarisurRehman can you post your cli app id and your visual builder app id (if they're different)?

Comment: @xavdid I think app id is 84185 as shown in https://imgur.com/MfGOc40. Its the same cli-app that is pushed to Zapier to be used in Zap. While creating Zap, it gives error as described in question.

Comment: @HarisurRehman can you email into `partners@zapier.com` with a copy of the unit test you're running locally that's working? I took a look and the nothing looks out of place, but our request logs are truncated.

Comment: @xavdid Just sent the whole project to partners@zapier.com so that you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root issue is that fancyhands expects a UTC timestamp for the `call_window_start` param (like `2020-02-29T11:00:00Z`). On the other hand, Zapier takes `datetime` fields and sends them to the developer in `bundle.inputData` as TZ-aware (`2020-03-02T05:09:08-05:00`).

The solution is therefore to remote the timezone data from the incoming timestamp. Maybe something like `new Date(bundle.inputData.call_window_start).toISOString()`.

Comment: Thanks, yep thats what I doubted as well that some kind of operation (aka encoding) is being applied. I changed call_window_start type to string instead of datetime to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In your picture the datetime string is one time missing a `Z` at the end and the other time it has a `Z`.
Try adding/removing the `Z`.

If that does not work something may be wrong with the HTTP headers. Locally and on Zapier you might be sending the content as a json the other time as a string.
Make sure that also matches with the CLI.

Comment: The Z comes in the response. I previously tried removing Z and sending request, but still same issue. I am sending "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" header from cli which works. Others don't work from cli. Also if I remove call_window_start, the UI works fine with other parameters.